# How can I get Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() with amplify and Microsoft OAuth after successfully authenticated?

Tags: oauth-2.0, graphql, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

My applications should login with Microsoft account (OAuth Provider). I got stuck to get user info after successfully authenticated.

I'm using two authentication types ( login-password and login with azure) , My shema.graphQl is with **authorisation rules private** , and I can get ***Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()*** with login password, but when I choose the microsoft authentication I get the access token and the redirection passed successfully , but ***Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()*** doesn't return user info, so I can't call the graphQls APIs!

**shema.graphQl**

```
type User @model @searchable @auth(rules: [{allow: private}]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  name: String!
  email: String!
  points: Int!
  phone: String!
}
```

**Login with Microsoft**
*https://test-auth-ino.auth.eu-central-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=MyOrganisationProviderAzure&redirect_uri=https://feature-test-auth0.abcdefghijk.amplifyapp.com/auth/login.auth.eu-central-2.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse&response_type=token&client_id=45dffffffd5fdf5e45ee87s&scope=email*

***result after redirection :***

```
https://feature-test-auth0.abcdefghijk.amplifyapp.com/auth/login.auth.eu-central-2.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse#access_token=eyJraWQiOiJFS1daODd3WffVJWQ1gwXC9kVklZSVo5eUdwaGdkcFwvb3BcL3ZySjhqcDhlcW1jPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.jw8zbgpctZPcdv6D6wo-qGKHG08HF31cq1G93whmly1CSSURi03nLOPma2xiy1t-wxSMlIDNr4ABcb8-IMqTnngZ4E4EAXnzKuxzhRJona2pV9ECl_EhROiq_aU6A72sbFz_B7u-FBRSR6De-uU3VO4lPC2DN5I3Ric7i4avxbvBUJ3DP6wq_UEqa3KPuoxi4A53P8y7Ovn3w1VGsaOOrLqelQ68Tn6bE_HCA6M23PZqF4fosjDmf_mnXrJ09bjXUVt6leQnYfQvCnvNTSXldHWtpCwMC6Gjab4NeTy8Urd0wY2GOXdES71tBDwf25zN3QbYpkPno-u1i1ryoGBW0Q&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

Comment: Hi @munirmounir, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please `enable the setting for bypasscache:true by modifying the code for amplify` as below: -

```
 Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true}).then(
 (user: CognitoUser) => this.setUser(user),
  _err => {
 console.error(_err)
 this._authState.next(initialAuthState)
 }
```

As per above, the first instruction in **setUser** might be **localstorage.clear()** which got removed by the above command post which you should be able to get user info with Microsoft authentication.

•   Once the above has been done successfully, then you can surely get the `user info as follows which can further be passed on to the graphQI APIs`: -

```
function getUser() {
return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
  .then(userData => userData)
  .catch(() => console.log('Not signed in'));
 }

function getSessionInfo() {
Auth.currentSession().then(res=>{
  debugger
  let access_token = res.getAccessToken()
  let id_token = res.getIdToken()
  let refresh_token = res.getRefreshToken();

  setAccessToken(access_token);
  setIdToken(id_token);
  })
  }
```

For more information regarding this, kindly refer to the documentation link below for amplify: -

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#retrieve-current-authenticated-user

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5167